# Django import models.py FK error

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship

I've a model in `notifications` app.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, primary_key = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

And another model in `Server` App.

```
from modules.notifications.models import * # importing notification's model

class Server(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_as_dict(server):
        server_notification_mapping_obj = ServerNotificationMapping.objects.filter(server = server)
        notifications_list = [obj.notification.name for obj in server_notification_mapping_obj]

        return  {
                    'id':server.id, 
                    'url':server.url,
                    'notifications':notifications_list
                }




class ServerNotificationMapping(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey('Server', related_name = 'servers')
    notification = models.ForeignKey('Notification',related_name = 'notifications')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("server", "notification"),)
```

Even though I'm importing the model from the Notifications app, I'm still getting an error saying

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fb523bad0c8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 314, in validate
    raise CommandError("One or more models did not validate:\n%s" % error_text)
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
servers.servernotificationmapping: 'notification' has a relation with model Notification, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (use actual class name rather than a string):

```
class ServerNotificationMapping(models.Model):
    server = models.ForeignKey('Server', related_name = 'servers')
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification,related_name = 'notifications')
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("server", "notification"),)
```

Comment: Thanks...it worked....But 1 question. does it effect the relationship? Also, I've other FK relations as well, in which I've provided the class name inside `''` , so shall I remove those as well? What's the best practise?

Comment: Also, is it recommended to have specific models.py file for different app or all the models should be combined in one app. The disadvantage for having different models in different app is that I've to `schemamigrate` and `migrate` different apps differently. So, which one is recommended?

Comment: The convention is to use the actual class rather than a string of the class name. so yes it is better to do the same for other FK relations. It does not affect the relationship, but it is probably something to do with how django retrospect the class.

Comment: Yes it is recommended to have separate models.py for each app.